# Open multiple files and immediately accept the prompt

Tags: python, linux, windows, file

I'm trying to create an application using pygtk. 
In the application I'm downloading multiple files and opening them with another application. Each opening of file results in a prompt for confirmation to open the file.
My goal is to make the confirmation automatically from my app, that way the user won't be obliged to repeatedly confirm each file. 
Is there any way to do that ?

The opening part of my application:

```
if platform.system().lower().startswith('linux'):
        subprocess.call(["xdg-open", path])

elif platform.system().lower().startswith('windows'):
        os.startfile(path)
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: so `subprocess.call(["xdg-open", path])` needs confirmation?

Comment: For example if you open a file with uTorrent, it will ask you if you want to add the file to the torrents' list, I would like it to skip the question by making uTorrent (or what ever application) autamitcally accept it

Comment: Not sure you could or would want to blanketly accept any file

Comment: I thought about simulating {enter} press on the keyboard. that way the files will be automatically accepted but it's unstable and feels bad... I would like to avoid that and I wonder how..